# What harm can moles do to my garden?

Tags: lawn, pest-control, pest-damage

In the last year, we've started seeing more and more moles in our large lawn area... From the odd hill at one corner to many all over.

I know moles are a big problem for those aiming for perfectly manicured lawns but other than cosmetic, what damage can they do to my lawn and garden; is it important to get rid of them out are they fairly innocuous?

Comment: As an aside, moles are quite territorial so it is unlikely that your population of moles is growing (you probably only have one). Heavy rain and searching for a mate in Spring are likely to result in increased molehill production. They dislike vibration, so children playing and regular lawn mowing tend to discourage them.

Answer (score 5):

They are not a source of anything other than a bit of a nuisance - their tunnels might mean they've destroyed some roots of plants as they make them, but they don't eat plant material. Molehills in lawns make it difficult to mow, so there is a need to remove those to try to keep the lawn somewhat level. More information here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=203

Answer (score 1):

Root damage to valuable, rare plants can be a problem. Also, other creatures can use
the mole tunnels to the garden's detriment. I had my covered, raised vegetable beds invaded by rats repeatedly one winter, using the existing network of mole tunnels. They did considerable damage.

Comment: Rats are quite capable of tunnelling by themselves, voles are also expert tunnelers and eat roots.